# placing the matrix image at the center of the imageview

Tags: android, imageview, zooming

**> I am scaling the image for zooming, after that i want to place the scaled image at the center of the imageview. how can i do this??**

```
    imageview.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
    savedMatrix.set(matrix);
    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
    matrix.setScale(.3f, .3f,screen_width/2,screen_height/2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
matrix.postTranslate((screen_width-image_width)/2, (screen_height-image_height)/2);
```

BTW, why are you doing:

```
savedMatrix.set(matrix);
matrix.set(savedMatrix);
```

once you deep copy matrix into savedMatrix they are identical so no need to do the other way.